# AMD GPU Hardware acceleration possible for FFMPEG encoding H.265 on FreeBSD 13.0?

Tags: freebsd, ffmpeg, gpu, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I am trying to record my live webcam video using FFMPEG to encode and record it in H.265 using my AMD Radeon RX 580 GPU.

Are there any AMD AMF drivers which works for FreeBSD?

Have no idea how to get this to work.

Also how can I watch the live video stream from my USB 3.0 webcam?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Because I prefer using the Unix system.

Comment: I would start [here](https://wiki.freebsd.org/Graphics) and install proper drivers first. Then obtain a version of `ffmpeg` that supports hardware acceleration using `amdgpu`. Check if this version of ffmpeg supports h265 by issuing this command `ffmpeg -encoders -hide_banner`.

Comment: @Michal Przybylowicz Thanks for the helpful reply. I am using Linux and it works well for FFMPEG GPU acceleration. FreeBSD is able to use GPU acceleration for chrome and x11, wondered if it world work for FFMPEG as well. Will try to see if there is a FFMPEG version which has amdgpu.